# water flow difference between 1/4 turn and multi turn shut off valve

Tags: plumbing

I replace my multi turn toilet shutoff valve with a 1/4 turn shutoff valve, now the water flow is much slower is there a difference in the amount of water that flows through the 1/4 turn valve

Comment: Did you properly [bleed the lines in your entire house](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63475/concerns-about-broken-washer-found-in-water-supply) after shutting off the main valve?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the make and model of the valve. If you look at the size of the water passage (sometimes referred to as the "port") you will get an idea of the size of the restriction. I have found that cheap imported 1/4 turn stop valves frequently have a small port. Whereas higher quality valves (more $$) may have a larger port or may even be "full port".

Comment: Try going to an actual plumbing supply shop, rather than a "big-box" store. You may find some 1/4 turn stop valves with less flow restriction. Also, make sure you do not have some other problem, like debris plugging your valve, supply line, or toilet fill valve. It is fairly common for scale or debris to be dislodged when changing out stop valves, toilet fill valves are particularly susceptible to debris problems.

Comment: Port size needs to equal pipe ID size. I've seen what essentially is a 1/2" id port on a 3/4" pipe valve. Throw it at the store's purchasing agent, being sure to leave a dent. The worst are the ball valves you get for use with garden hose. The ball valve port may be only 3/8" on a 5/8" hose, stinks if you're on gravity feed irrigation.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I was under the impression that the effects of a momentary restriction were negligible (at 40psi) and that most all valves do restrict. I'd have to go with junk in the lines (or the fill valve, now) or a new line was used that's smaller.

Comment: @mazura: Nope. Think about it: A partly open valve is a "momentary restriction". That's hardly negligible. Water in incompressible, remember.

Answer (score -1):

I estimate 30% to 40% flow rate restriction, for the stop/globe and 1/4-turn ball valves/bibbs commonly available for 3/4" garden hoses. Large inner-diameter 1/4-turn ball valves are also available with little to no flow rate restriction for 3/4" garden hoses.  These typically have long handles, of several inches, while the restrictive ball valves typically have small handles, less than one inch.  It is also easy to see the size difference of the ball and ball shroud, inside.

Comment: OP was asking about toilet supply shut-off valves rather than outdoor faucets :) Thanks for your interest here, though!